# How to fill null values with a aggregate of a group using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple dataset with some null values:

```
Age,Title
10,Mr
20,Mr
null,Mr
1, Miss
2, Miss
null, Miss
```

I want to fill the nulls values with the aggregate of the grouping by a different column (in this case, Title). E.g. the Mean of the Title column is:

```
15, Mr
1.5, Miss
```

So the final result should look like this:

```
Age,Title
10,Mr
20,Mr
15,Mr
1, Miss
2, Miss
1.5, Miss
```

I have seen a lot of examples using **Pandas** using **Transform**:

```
df["Age"] = df.groupby("Title").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

I am trying not to use external libraries and do it natively in pyspark. The python dataframe does not have a transform method.

I was thinking of storing the aggregates in a separate dataframe like this:

```
meanAgeDf = df.groupBy("Title").mean("Age").select("Title", col("avg(Age)").alias("AgeMean"))
```

and then for each grouping lookup the Title and fill all those values with that mean value:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
x = df.join(meanAgeDf, "Title").withColumn("AgeMean", when(col("Age").isNull(), col("AgeMean")).otherwise(col("Age")))
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in one step using window function `avg`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,avg
w = Window.partitionBy(df.title)
res = df.withColumn("mean_col",avg(df.age).over(w))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome! Now... how would I do the same thing but with Median? There does not seem to be a Median window function and a UDF with approxQuantile does not work

Comment: you can probably use `percent_rank`?

Comment: Am I missing something here? it seems this answer will just add a mean_col column with the mean values of each group. That is not what the user asked I suppose. The user wants to fill the missing values with the mean from each group.